# iOS eureka-forms LabelRow hidden condition not evaluating

Tags: ios, swift3, eureka-forms

## Setup

- Swift 3.1
- iOS 10.0
- Eureka 3.0

## Problem

Can not make a `LabelRow` hide together with a `TextAreaRow` hidden state. The label is defined before adding both to a section. It gets added on top of the text.

## Code

After a few different ways to define the `Condition`, when debugging, it seems the function is not getting called. Only in the first 2 it gets called once, but not when the `TextAreaRow` changes to hide or show

```
    let switchRowTag = "switchRowTag"
    form +++ section
        <<< SwitchRow(switchRowTag) { row in
            row.title = "Select me"}

    // Test hiding functions ========================
    let tag = "textArea"
    let title = "Test Hiding"
    let labelTag = "\(tag)_label"
    let textArea = TextAreaRow(tag) {
        $0.title = title
        $0.tag = tag
        $0.placeholder = title
        $0.textAreaHeight = .dynamic(initialTextViewHeight: 110)
        $0.hidden = Condition.predicate(NSPredicate(format: "$\(switchRowTag) == false"))
    }
    let labelRow = LabelRow(labelTag) {
        $0.title = title
        $0.tag = labelTag
        /* try setting the function after adding to the section
        $0.hidden = Condition.function([tag], { form in
            if let textRow = form.rowBy(tag: tag) as? TextAreaRow {
                return textRow.isHidden
            } else {
                return false
            }
        })
         */
    }

    section <<< labelRow <<< textArea
    // Is never evaluated
    /*
    labelRow.hidden = Condition.function([tag], { form in
        if let textRow = form.rowBy(tag: tag) as? TextAreaRow {
            return textRow.isHidden
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
     */
    if let labelRow = form.rowBy(tag: labelTag) as? LabelRow {
        labelRow.hidden = Condition.function([tag], { form in
            if let textRow = form.rowBy(tag: tag) as? TextAreaRow {
                return textRow.isHidden
            } else {
                return false
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: It seems there is no easy way to add a title to a TextAreaRow, so I was trying to add a LabelRow. The reason to want the condition come from the other row's hidden state, is that the conditions are all processed separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not supported.

Eureka supports only reevaluating the hidden conditions, when the row related by the tag depended upon has a **change of value only**. Not a change of visibility (r[ef](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#hiding-using-a-function-condition)).